# How to make a function which will execute when classes of two elements get equal?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I am trying to create a webpage which has 2 paragraphs, and I have given them 2 different classes. Using JavaScript, I have created a function which will change their classes to same when clicked. I want to execute a function which will change text of one paragraph, when the class of both paragraph gets same after the click.

```js
var firstPara = document.getElementById('firstPara');
var secondPara = document.getElementById('secondPara');

function changeClass1() {
firstPara.classList.remove("class1");
firstPara.classList.add("sameClass");
}

function changeClass2() {
secondPara.classList.remove("class2");
secondPara.classList.add("sameClass");
}

var class1 = firstPara.className;
var class2 = secondPara.className;

function changeText() {
   if (class1 === class2) {
   firstPara.innerHTML = "The text is changed!";
 }
}
changeText();
```

```html
<p id="firstPara" class="class1" onClick="changeClass1()"> This is first Paragraph. </p>
<p id="secondPara" class="class2" onClick="changeClass2()"> This is second Paragraph. </p>
```

> To know that the class of paragraphs is changed, I have given different colors of the text to all the classes using CSS. When I click on the Paragraphs, their colour get changed i.e their classes get changed, but when I click both the paragraphs, and their colour get same i.e they get same classes, the last function of changing the text doesn't execute. I am a beginner in JavaScript and I don't know much about it. Can anyone tell me solution of this problem, why the function is not executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your changeText function after each onClick event to see if some changes were made. Also the variables where you store your classnames should be within the function.

Example:

```js
var firstPara = document.getElementById('firstPara');
var secondPara = document.getElementById('secondPara');

function changeClass1() {
  firstPara.classList.remove("class1");
  firstPara.classList.add("sameClass");
  changeText();
}

function changeClass2() {
  secondPara.classList.remove("class2");
  secondPara.classList.add("sameClass");
  changeText();
}

function changeText() {
  const class1 = firstPara.className;
  const class2 = secondPara.className;

  if (class1 === class2) {
    firstPara.innerHTML = "The text is changed!";
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="firstPara" class="class1" onClick="changeClass1()"> This is first Paragraph. </p>
<p id="secondPara" class="class2" onClick="changeClass2()"> This is second Paragraph. </p>
```

Comment: Oh Sorry!! I had written wrong declaration and wrong value of variable class2 by mistake. I changed it now. The function still doesn't execute. Can you help me?

Comment: @DivyanshuTiwari I posted a demo example, please have look at it, should work now

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks for help. You literally solved my problem. I hope I could follow you somewhere.